# Cannot run Eclipse Java project in visual studio code (Could not find or load main class)

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I want to move from Eclipse to Visual Studio Code, I can open project completely. Visual Studio Code can recognize `.classpath` and vice versa.

[Visual Studio Code can recognize Java project as same as Eclispse do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkDkf.png)

Then I go to the java file with Main method and run. It show error as

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.untitled.game.Game
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.untitled.game.Game

I never install Code Runner and I tried to clean workspace by cleaning the java server workspace, and nothing work. It still have a same problem.

However, this project can run in Eclipse before and never have a problem.

PS. After I followed this [instuction.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) I can create Java project in VS Code and run properly. But if I run Java project from Eclipse, it's still has the same problem. (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)

[image: Create Java project in VS Code and run the project.]

PS.1 If my Java project is not in Windows drive, the VS Code stills shows an error althougth reconfigured `.setting` as same as Java project that freshly created from VS Code.

Comment: VS Code does not support Java without an additional extension. Did you install an extension for Java language support and if yes, which extension(s) exactly? With [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) you will move from Eclipse to Eclipse with VS Code as UI.

Comment: Yes, I'm already installed Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat.

Comment: [Lol](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/1358189525424459777) (consider to improve your question). Do not ignore the problem which is shown in your screenshot. Delete the .class file in the `bin` folder and check whether it will be recreated when editing and saving the corresponding .java file. Look inside the .argfile that contains the arguments whether the `bin` folder is included on the classpath.

Comment: @howlger I'm tried to deleted all files in `bin` folder and run again, it's still has the same error and `class` files is not created.

Comment: When the `.class` files in the `bin` folder are not re-created, your project is not correct configured.

Comment: How could I reconfigure the Eclipse Java project again in VS Code?

Comment: Create a new Java project and compare the `.project` and `.classpath` file and the `.settings` folder with those of the existing project.

Comment: Finally I can run Java project with VS Code but only if the project location is in the Windows drive, in other drive such as D:, it still caused the error `java.lang.ClassNotFountException` because it build the `.argfiles` in `%TEMP%` folder, in the other hand, newly created java project from vs code can run even location is not in Windows drive or drive C:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I can run the Eclipse java project in vscode with settings from `.vscode` folder.

First, open Java project folder normally.

Then creates folder `.vscode` at the root of project and creates two files, `settings.json` and `launch.json`.

In `settings.json` file, add project configurations as follows.

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

Run the project again, you will see an error, don't worry, vscode will add the configuration automatically.
In `launch.json` file, you will see the configurations like this.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Launch Game",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.untitled.game.Game",
      "projectName": "Alien Hunter",
    }
  ]
}
```

In case of running the project that the location is outside from Windows drive, it still has an error because it shortened the `-cp "path"` command into the `.argfile` that saved in `%temp%` folder and called when running the project.

Add configuration to fix the problem.

```
"shortenCommandLine": "none"
```

If there have a native library in Eclipse, in case of my project, I'm using `LWJGL`, I will add configuration as follows.

```
"vmArgs": "-Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/native/windows"
```

If the project has the resources in another folder outside of `src` folder, for example, `res` folder, right-click on the folder and select `Add Folder to Java Source Path`, the project can be able to access the resource files.

launch.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Launch Game",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.untitled.game.Game",
      "projectName": "Alien Hunter",
      "vmArgs": "-Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/native/windows",
      "shortenCommandLine": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.Are you just starting to use vscode? If so, please check whether the Java interpreter is selected correctly, whether several necessary extensions are installed, and the necessary extensions are mentioned in this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial). I hope they can help you.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? I think I need more information to help you deal with the problem

Comment: Sorry, I'm moved back to Eclipse for a while, after I followed this [instuction](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) I can create Java project in VS Code and run properly, but if I run Java project from Eclipse, It's still has a same problem.

Comment: I think we can start with the reason for the error "ClassNotFound". Since vscode can be created and run normally, I think this may be caused by some different configurations between eclipse and vscode. We can exclude and analyze them one by one according to the content provided in this article ：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean/18093929#18093929